# Make get calls in angular js after a small time of key up event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, timeout, angular-http

I am beginner in angular js, In my application I am using a web api that provides, place when we enter pincode. I am calling a function in my controller on keyup event of textfield, but it throws some error, and some time not makes the get call in proper. is there any way to resolve this ?, what actually I need is, make api calls only when user stops or waits to enter next key in the textfield

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-keyup="check();" ng-model="place" placeholder="Enter a pincode"/>
    <p>{{data.city}}</p>
```

**Controller.js**

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.check = function(){
    var req = {
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'https://sphirelabs-indian-pin-codes.p.mashape.com/pincode.php?code='+$scope.place,
         headers: {
            "Key": "api key",
            "Accept": "application/json"
         },
        }

    $http(req).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.data =  data;
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            conosole.log("Error");
          })



    };


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ng-keyup` event. Just wrap your input in the form and call `check()` function when you send this form by using `ng-submit`:

```
<form ng-submit="check()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="place" placeholder="Enter a pincode"/>
</form>
<p>{{data.city}}</p>
```

So when you enter pincode in your input and hit enter key, `check()` function will be called.